# Как оставить слово из квадратных скобок

Tags: php

Дается задание на php, квадратные скобки убрал с помощью регулярных выражении. Напишите скрипт, который выявляет слова в квадратных скобках [].
 Пример работы:
 Пришла строка "London is the capital of [Great Britain]", ответ должен быть "Great Britain".
На эту задачу у меня вышло так:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 $txt='London is the capital of [Great Britain]';

  $re1='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re2='\[(\w+.\w+)';   # Square Braces 1

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $sbraces1=$matches[1][0];
      print "$sbraces1 <br>";
  }
$string1 = "Меня зовут [Игорь Петрович], вот мой номер [77051234569]";

$string2 = "Меня [зовут] [Игорь Петрович], вот мой номер [77051234569]";
$re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='\[(\W+)\]';
$re3='\[(\d+)\]';
  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2."/is", $string1, $matches1))
  {
      $sbraces1=$matches1[1][0];
      print "$sbraces1 \n";
  }
  if ($c = preg_match_all("/".$re1.$re3."/is", $string2, $matches2)) {
    $sbraces1=$matches2[1][0];
    print "$sbraces1 \n";
  }
```

Как объединить два регулярных выражении во втором примере?
Напишите функцию которая принимает массив, и определяет какое наибольшое число подряд идущих элементов последовательности равны друг другу. Данное задание у меня получилось но оно считает каждое с помощью данной функции:

```
$test = array(5, 8, 8, 8, 11, 5, 9); 

echo "<div>";
print_r(array_count_values($test));
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вариант абсолютно правильно все делает, вы уже нашли количество повторений. Осталось только отсортировать по убыванию получившийся массив, например с помощью http://php.net/manual/ru/function.arsort.php

```
$test = array(5, 8, 8, 8, 11, 5, 9); 
// Посчитали количество
$array = array_count_values($test);
// Отсортировали по убыванию, сохранив связь "ключ->значение"
arsort($array);
// Вывели первый элемент массива
print current($array);
```

Если решать задачу без использования функций PHP (или на другом языке)..

На входе имеем набор значений, на выходе должны сказать максимальное число последовательно идущих равных элементов. Очень простое решение "в лоб" заключается в подсчете одинаковых решений с сохранением предыдущего и счетчиком:

```
$test = array(5, 8, 11, 11, 11, 5, 5, 9, 9); 
$prev = NULL; // Предыдущий элемент, на старте неопределен
$counter = 0; // Счетчик последовательно идущих одинаковых элементов
$max_counter = 0; // Счетчик максимального числа последовательно идущих элементов

foreach ($test as $item) {
    if ($prev == $item) {
        // Если предыдущий сохраненный элемент равен текущему, то
        // увеличиваем значение счетчика
        $counter++;
    } else {
        // а если не равен, то запоминаем максимальный счетчик, которого удалось достичь
        if ($max_counter < $counter) {
            $max_counter = $counter;
        }
        // Сбрасываем текущий счетчик максимального числа элементов и запоминаем новый
        // предыдущий элемент
        $counter = 1; // Значение 1 выбрано потому, что как минимум 1 элемент уже есть
        $prev = $item;
    }
}

print $max_counter;
```

Comment: Сформулируйте еще раз задания, хотя бы разбив их на абзацы
Судя по уровню, это задания максимум старшей школы.

По поводу буквы Е - это простое задание, не думаю что этот сайт подходит для решения школьных задачек

Comment: Посмотри на код где нужно убрать квадратные скобки. Мне теперь надо их объединить чтобы две значения выводилось.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на документацию к функции preg_match_all, она выбирает все подошедшие конструкции, а не только первую. Не нужно делать два вызова, все результаты уже есть в `$matches`. Также советую посетить https://regex101.com/ - сократит время на понимание того, как работают regexp и что же они возвращают. Удачи )

Comment: Например ваш пример можно разобрать вот так: https://regex101.com/r/owZL3a/1 Обратите внимание на сам regexp и на флаги `g` и `m` (для многострочного текста, читайте описание флагов). А чтобы понять, где же эти значения и как их вынуть из `$matches`, лучше выведите `print_r($matches)` после выполнения `preg_match_all`, и все сразу станет понятно.

Comment: Если так как вы говорили, но мне по условию надо вывести данные две значения: его инициалы и номер